# Ping test for a javascript discord bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dn9ct.png)

I have use this javascript program for my discord bot but when I use the command "!ping" in discord, the bot don't reply

Even if it is online, it does not work

I don't know what I can do for change this

Can I have help ?

Comment: Finally, I have fond the solution !

I had forgotten the folder, so the bot couldn't connect to discord

but now, that ok, the bot reply to my commands !

Answer (score 0):

The `message` event has been changed to `messageCreate`, try changing it to that, also you should use `message.member` instead of `message.author.member`. If that doesn't fix anything then the issue is most likely with the startup.

E.g.

```js
client.on('messageCreate', async message => {
    if (message.content === "!ping") {
        message.channel.send(`Pong`);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand ^^'

Comment: oh... It's don't work... so It's probably a other problème than my program

Answer (score -1):

In my own bot, i use this code

```
// A chaque message sur le Discord.
client.on('message', async message => {
    //Définition des variables
    let member = message.author.member;
    if (message.content.startsWith("!ping")) {
        // On envoi un MP avec le Bot
        message.channel.send(`Pong`);
        message.delete();
    }
}
```

This code is actually ok and use in 3 bots on 5 discords for me. The difference between my code and your, is the

```
client.on('message', async message =>
```

Comment: I tried your code but my bot didn't answer...

I have tried many other codes, but none worked

On discord, he is online, but it does not respond to any commands

Comment: has you any error on console ? has you try to take some 'console.log(message)' for seeing if Bot receive the message ?

Comment: It's don't work... So, It's probably a problème with my initialization program

Comment: How would it answer OP's question? `async` is not needed in OP's code... Neither in yours.

Comment: it is a part of my own code, not all the code, and i need it in my. I have just indicate that this is the only difference between his and my code.